# MySQL query gone wild?

Tags: sql, mysql

Can anyone tell me why the following is happening, and how to fix it?

I have a MySQL query with an ORDER BY clause that looks like this..

```
ORDER BY (did_voteup-did_votedown) DESC, did_voteup DESC
```

So it should order the results by their "effective" rating, as in..

```
1st. 10 up - 1 down = 9 effective
2nd. 10 up - 5 down = 5 effective
3rd. 10 up - 7 down = 3 effective
```

However, as you can see on [my page here](http://vilegaming.com/dictionary.php?id=4), it's ordering them wrong, and giving me this..

```
1st. 1 up - 3 down = -2 effective
2nd. 16 up - 6 down = 10 effective
3rd. 15 up - 5 down = 10 effective
```

Obviously, that 1st place row shouldn't be there.

---

More information..

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary_definitions (
  did_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  did_wordid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  did_userid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  did_status tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  did_date int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  did_definition text,
  did_example text,
  did_votecheck int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  did_voteup smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  did_votedown smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (did_id),
  KEY (did_wordid),
  KEY (did_userid)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

SELECT a.did_id, a.did_userid, a.did_definition, a.did_example, 
    a.did_votecheck, a.did_voteup, a.did_votedown, b.user_name, b.user_extra8 
FROM dictionary_definitions AS a LEFT JOIN users AS b ON a.did_userid=b.user_id 
WHERE did_wordid=4 
ORDER BY (did_voteup-did_votedown) DESC, did_voteup DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Looks like data type problem, can you please show the entire query and structure of the table please?

Comment: As David said, if the field is a string it will put 1, 10, 2 type of craziness.

Comment: Appended the original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a known [issue regarding subtraction from unsigned integers](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46799).

Subtraction between integer values, where one is of type UNSIGNED, produces an unsigned
result by default. If the result would otherwise have been negative, it becomes the
maximum integer value. If the `NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION` SQL mode is enabled, the result is
negative.

Reference: [Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)