# Decrement in mysql goes past zero

Tags: mysql, limit, decrement

I am trying to do this in mysql:

UPDATE table SET value = value - 1 WHERE blah blah

If value is 0 and this is run value is set to 4294967295. This is because it is an unsigned integer so it is looping round back to the maximum value.

How would I go about making it stay on zero instead? Can I do this purely in the sql?

Comment: FYI: Subtraction between integer values, where one is of type UNSIGNED, produces an unsigned result by default. If the result would otherwise have been negative, it becomes the maximum integer value. If the NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION SQL mode is enabled, the result is negative: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517556/mysql-query-gone-wild

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
`AND value > 0`
```

Comment: *facepalm* Obviously. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
SET value = IF(value=0,0,value-1)
```

Comment: Yes, that's why he got my upvote too. But it's not the only possible solution :-)

Comment: I'll use rob's as it's simpler, but it's interesting that you can do this.

Comment: It depends if you want to update other columns in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Use the where clause  to say value > 0

Sunday night SQL always hurts me too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just append to the SQL string `AND value > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can run a second query or if-statement, checking whether it is set to the maximum and set it back to 0.
But this is some kind of stupid...

Write a quick function which checks the entry, if it is already 0 do not perform any update query.

**`(if value >= 0, do not perform xy)`**